# Missing corner button in QTableWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I'm using pyqt5 and from what I read so far the top-left corner cell should be created automatically. I have this little popup window in which I create the table and fill it with values from a dictionary:

```
class LimitTable(QWidget):
    query = QtCore.pyqtSignal(dict)

    def __init__(self, dic):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.dic = dic
        self.setup_ui()
        self.setWindowTitle("Limit Table")

    def setup_ui(self):
        self.limit_table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self)
        self.limit_table.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 681, 81))
        self.limit_table.setObjectName("limit_table")

        row_names = ["Lower Limit", "Upper Limit"]
        col_names = list(self.dic.keys())
        self.limit_table.setRowCount(len(row_names))
        self.limit_table.setColumnCount(len(self.dic.keys()))
        self.limit_table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(col_names)

        helpers.add_header(self.limit_table, len(row_names),
                           row_names, "vertical")
        helpers.add_header(self.limit_table, len(col_names), col_names)

        for i, val in enumerate(self.dic.values()):
            self.limit_table.setItem(0, i,
                                     QTableWidgetItem("{:0.1e}".format(val[0])))
            self.limit_table.setItem(1, i,
                                     QTableWidgetItem("{:0.1e}".format(val[1])))
```

where add_header is just

```
def add_header(tab_obj, count, name, hv="horizontal"):
    """Adds header objects to TableWidget.

    Args:
        - tab_obj (QTableWidget) : table object
        - count (int) : number of cells
        - name (str) : header name
        - hv (str) : choose horizontal or vertical header
    """
    tab_obj.setColumnCount(count)
    for col in range(0, count):
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        if isinstance(name, dict):
            item.setText(list(name.keys())[col])
        if isinstance(name, list):
            item.setText(name[col])
        if hv == "horizontal":
            tab_obj.setHorizontalHeaderItem(col, item)
            adjust_header(tab_obj, count, "Stretch")
        if hv == "vertical":
            tab_obj.setVerticalHeaderItem(col, item)
    return True
```

So in principle it's very basic and according to text book. The lines "setRowCount" and "setColumnCount" should do what I want. But instead I get this

[image]

**Update 1**

Apperently, the corner button is there...

```
self.limit_table.isCornerButtonEnabled()
```

returns True. I also tried specifically setting it to True. Nothing changes. Also, when I use QtDesigner or when I create any other table I get the same result: Can't distinguish the corner button from the column header or in other words, the column header cell of the first column spans all the way to the left table boarder. Can anyone relate to this?

**Update 2**

It is still unclear to me, why the corner button can't be seen as default in my tables. However, as [eyllanesc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6622587/eyllanesc) (thanks man!) pointed out correctly, the corner button can be edited with a style sheet. In pyqt it would look something like this:

```
    self.limit_table.setCornerButtonEnabled(True)
    self.limit_table.setStyleSheet("QTableCornerButton::section{border-width: 
    1px; border-color: #BABABA; border-style:solid;}")
```

which yields the following:

[image]

Comment: The corner widget exists, maybe you can not distinguish it but it is in the upper left corner, above "Lower Limit" and to the left of "CC".

Comment: Well, but it should be clearly distinguishable from the CC column. The grid line is missing, though.

Comment: Well, that's another thing, Have you already verified that the button exists?

Comment: What is the value of `self.limit_table.isCornerButtonEnabled() `? Try setting it explicitly with `self.limit_table.setCornerButtonEnabled(True)`

Comment: I tryed setCornerButtonEnabled already (before and after setting the row/column count). Also isCornerButtonEnabled is True so I guess the object should be there...

Comment: @dieggo111 What do you want to get? The button exists but it is not distinguishable.

Comment: @dieggo111 Use `QTableCornerButton::section {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #BABABA;
    border-style: solid;
}
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button is active, but not visible.

See the [Qt Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/search-results.html?q=qtablecornerbutton):

The corner widget in a QTableView is implemented as a QAbstractButton and can be styled using the "QTableView QTableCornerButton::section" selector.

Warning: If you only set a background-color on a QTableCornerButton, the background may not appear unless you set the border property to some value. This is because, by default, the **QTableCornerButton draws a native border which completely overlaps the background-color**.

The color of the grid can be specified using the gridline-color property.

See QAbsractScrollArea to style scrollable backgrounds.

See Customzing QTableView for an example.